# Cron job is not creating logs after running jar in Java

Tags: java, linux, logging, jar, cron

I run a cron job in Linux with jar files that executed successfully but the log file is not created.

```
*/10 * * * * java -jar /home/rrs/app.jar
```

Comment: What log file? cron will email you the output of the program it runs. Did you set up the email and check what it contains?

Comment: @Robert It's often the case that Java apps won't write much or anything to stdout. Usually it's log4j/logback writing to a file. It's unclear which they're referring to.

Comment: Configuring log4j.properties in this project using log4j api for generating tracks.log whenever chron will run , it will generate 'logFile/tracks.log' but cron not generated ,, Using direct jar command it generates successfully but crontab it is not generated.

Comment: Is the cron user the same as the user you're running manually with? Maybe it's a unix file permissions issue and the cron user can't write to that dir.

Comment: Ya , Michael cron user and loging user are same and permission also granted for this location .

Comment: Maybe you need to post an [MCVE] coded version of the problem. Good luck.